# How to output string inside a hash in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using HTTParty to get some information on the internet, which returns a hash. The hash is stored in @response. When printing @response, I get:

```
{"total":1,"page":0,"page_size":500,"result":[{"token_address":"0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e","token_id":"93621450588507963380282193080403618089126431025205794831153795070541439172609","amount":"1","owner_of":"0x0370dc008463c37b6a04c13ca3348aba11095eec","block_number":"12964809","block_number_minted":"12175962","contract_type":"ERC1155","token_uri":"https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/metadata/0x495f947276749Ce646f68AC8c248420045cb7b5e/93621450588507963380282193080403618089126431025205794831153795070541439172609","metadata":"{\"name\":\"Club Legends #44 | Henrik - Celtic\",\"description\":\"Club Legends #44\\n\\nHenrik - Celtic\\n\\nNFT soccer collectibles by 8-Bit Sport.\",\"external_link\":\"https://twitter.com/8bitsport\",\"image\":\"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/TgK-N_jozTkHIw6nUTnugU7MOMGWTNiYFlrxTY63Cbx7GtajExIeOPv2bBrqhJL0VRA6fdpT3yVDc9Kq62jJxd8H7rPLq0YaviWi\",\"animation_url\":null}","synced_at":"2021-06-23T17:40:18.322Z","name":"OpenSea Shared Storefront","symbol":"OPENSTORE"}]}
```

I would like to retrive the `name` inside the `metadata` and hence print out `"Club Legends #44 | Henrik - Celtic\"`. How would I go about this?

Comment: JSON.parse(@response["metadata"]) gives you the metadata as a hash. Then pull the values you need using the keys (e.g. "name")

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following code:

```
JSON.parse(@response.dig(:result, 0, :metadata) || '{}').dig('name')
```

This will return the string `"Club Legends #44 | Henrik - Celtic"` for the above hash, and if any of the sub-hashes could not be found (e.g. the `metadata` hash is missing), you'd get `nil` instead of an error.